# Парсинг и проверка полученной информации

Tags: php

1. Парсингом получаю блок в котором 10 чисел обернутых в span
2. Меня интересует только первое число
3. Раз в минуту происходит смещение на 1 позицию, последнее число из блока удаляется, в начало списка добавляется новое
4. Скрипт циклично проверяет раз в минуту появление нового числа
5. Числа могут повторяться, но их кол-во всегда равно 10
6. Полученное новое число сохраняется в таблицу

---

Проблема: дублирование чисел
Суть проблемы: числа могут повторяться, но не должны дублироваться, т.е. их кол-во в блоке всегда равно 10.

*Как проще и правильнее организовать проверку дублирования*, зная предыдущие числа, их кол-во, но с учетом, что каждое следующее число может быть таким же как и предыдущее?

Спасибо!

---

Прикладываю пример получаемых списков:

```html
<table width="100%" height="107" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="1" bordercolordark="white" bordercolorlight="black">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Проход № 1</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Проход № 2</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Проход № 3</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Проход № 4</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Проход № 5</font></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Время: 10:01</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Время: 10:02</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Время: 10:03</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Время: 10:04</font></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font size="2">Время: 10:05</font></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="gmroulette__rows">                
                <div class="gmroulette__row gmroulette__row--white">
                    <p align="center"><font size="2">21, 5, 5, 31, 6, 35, 23, 18, 0, 33</font></p>
                </div>
</div></td>
        <td>            
            <div class="gmroulette__row gmroulette__row--white">
                <p align="center"><b><font size="2">23</font></b><font size="2">, 21, 5, 5, 31, 6, 35, 23, 18, 0</font></p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>            
            <div class="gmroulette__row gmroulette__row--white">
                <p align="center"><b><font size="2">1</font></b><font size="2">, 23, 21, 5, 5, 31, 6, 35, 23, 18</font></p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>            
            <div class="gmroulette__row gmroulette__row--white">
                <p align="center"><b><font size="2">7, </font></b><font size="2">1, 23, </font><font size="2">21, </font><font size="2">5, 5, 31, 6, 35, 23</font></p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="gmroulette__row gmroulette__row--red">
                <div class="gmroulette__row gmroulette__row--white">
                    <p align="center"><b><font size="2">15, </font></b><font size="2">7<b>, </b>1<b>, </b>23<b>, </b></font><font size="2">21</font><font size="2"><b>, </b>5<b>, </b>5, 31, 6, 35</font></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Непонятно, где могут повторятся и где не должны дублироваться?

Comment: Eсли выполнить код примера, будет наглядно видно как это должно быть, жирным выделена цифра для визуального понимания смещения. С каждым последующим проходом - перемещается ниже, пока не исчезнет. Так же в примере есть две цифры 5, идущие друг за другом - это тоже допустимый расклад. На запрашиваемой странице примерно раз в 1 минуту в начале списка появляется новое число.

Comment: Всего 10 цифр в блоке, мне нужно получать новое число, которое появляется сверху, остальные уже сохранены. Я не понимаю как задать логику, чтобы в случае если новое число еще не появилось, повторно не парсилось "старое", т.к. на примере 5 я хотел показать, что повторы возможны, если они есть на самом деле, но иногда скрипт сохраняет уже сохраненное повтором.

Comment: для предыдущего парсинга запоминайте весь ряд цифр, можете его хешировать. При начале следущей итерации парсинга сравнивайте текущий хеш и сохраненный на предыдущем шаге. Если совпадает, то данные не менялись, если отличается - можете парсить.

Comment: имеете ввиду, просто сравнивать например сумму чисел?

Comment: если сравнивать сумму, то можно попасть на равные хэши 2+3 и 4+1, используйте, например, md5 для строки чисел "2,3,..."

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для предыдущего парсинга нужно запоминать весь ряд цифр, удобнее будет использовать его хеш. При начале следущей итерации парсинга нужно сравнить текущий хеш и сохраненный на предыдущем шаге.
Если хэши совпадают, то данные не менялись и парсить ничего не нужно. Если хэши отличаются, значит данные обновились и можно производить парсинг.

В качестве хэша можно брать md5 от строки с числами.

Comment: вопрос, а как быть, если новое число 0, такое тоже возможно и его тоже надо сохранять
или если новое число = последнему числу, которое "выпало" из списка. В этих случаях хеш тоже будет же неизменным?!

Comment: Хэш рассчитывается по строке, а не по числам. Хеш может совпасть только если строка из 10 одинаковых чисел и новое число добавиться такое же, какое и ушло.

Comment: Ок, теперь точно понял ))) Тогда, если я знаю, что у меня 1 число в минуту и всего 10 чисел, может быть добавлять к строке например десятку округленную полученную из текущего времени? или это бред?